# Completion block of animation is performed immediately

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uikit

I'm trying to remove the custom view from the superview after the end of the animation in the completion block, but it is called immediately and the animation becomes sharp. I managed to solve the problem in a not very good way: just adding a delay to remove the view.

Here is the function for animating the view:

```
private func animatedHideSoundView(toRight: Bool) {
   let translationX = toRight ? 0.0 : -screenWidth
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.soundView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: translationX, y: 0.0)
   } completion: { isFinished in
        if isFinished {
            self.soundView.removeFromSuperview()
            self.songPlayer.pause()
        }
    }
}
```

The problem in this line: `self.soundView.removeFromSuperview()`

When I call this function in the switch recognizer.state completion block statement it executes early and when elsewhere everything works correctly.

```
@objc private func soundViewPanned(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let touchPoint = recognizer.location(in: view)
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .began:
            initialOffset = CGPoint(x: touchPoint.x - soundView.center.x, y: touchPoint.y - soundView.center.y)
        case .changed:
            soundView.center = CGPoint(x: touchPoint.x - initialOffset.x, y: touchPoint.y - initialOffset.y)
            if notHiddenSoundViewRect.minX > soundView.frame.minX {
                animatedHideSoundView(toRight: false)
            } else if notHiddenSoundViewRect.maxX < soundView.frame.maxX {
                animatedHideSoundView(toRight: true)
            }
        case .ended, .cancelled:
            let decelerationRate = UIScrollView.DecelerationRate.normal.rawValue
            let velocity = recognizer.velocity(in: view)
            let projectedPosition = CGPoint(
                x: soundView.center.x + project(initialVelocity: velocity.x, decelerationRate: decelerationRate),
                y: soundView.center.y + project(initialVelocity: velocity.y, decelerationRate: decelerationRate)
            )
            let nearestCornerPosition = nearestCorner(to: projectedPosition)
            let relativeInitialVelocity = CGVector(
                dx: relativeVelocity(forVelocity: velocity.x, from: soundView.center.x, to: nearestCornerPosition.x),
                dy: relativeVelocity(forVelocity: velocity.y, from: soundView.center.y, to: nearestCornerPosition.y)
            )
            let timingParameters = UISpringTimingParameters(dampingRatio: 0.8, initialVelocity: relativeInitialVelocity)
            let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.5, timingParameters: timingParameters)
            animator.addAnimations {
                self.soundView.center = nearestCornerPosition
            }
            animator.startAnimation()
        default: break
        }
    }
```

I want the user to be able to swipe this soundView off the screen.

That's why I check where the soundView is while the user is moving it, so that if he moves the soundView near the edge of the screen, I can hide the soundView animatedly.

Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but I couldn't think of anything else, because I don't have much experience. Could someone give me some advice on this?

I managed to solve it this way, but I don't like it:

```
private func animatedHideSoundView(toRight: Bool) {
    let translationX = toRight ? 0.0 : -screenWidth
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.soundView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: translationX, y: 0.0)
    }        
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
        self.soundView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.songPlayer.pause()
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kZXz.gif)

You can see and run all code here: https://github.com/swiloper/AnimationProblem

Comment: That doesn't seem right. The completion block shouldn't fire until after the duration of the animation. You might try having the body of the animation change the view's frame.origin.x rather than changing it's transform and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Can share how and where are you calling animatedHideSoundView?

Comment: @Asteroid he shared on the github link

Comment: When you keep panning the your soundView might be removed from superview in the previous animation call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple notes...

First, in your controller code, you are calling `animatedHideSoundView()` from your pan gesture recognizer ***every time you move the touch***. It's unlikely that's what you want to do.

Second, if you call `animatedHideSoundView(toRight: true)` your code:

```
private func animatedHideSoundView(toRight: Bool) {
   let translationX = toRight ? 0.0 : -screenWidth
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.soundView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: translationX, y: 0.0)
   } completion: { isFinished in
        if isFinished {
            self.soundView.removeFromSuperview()
            self.songPlayer.pause()
        }
    }
}
```

sets `translationX` to `Zero` ... when you then try to animate the transform, the animation will take **no time** because you're not changing the `x`.

Third, I **strongly** suggest that you start simple. The code you linked to cannot be copy/pasted/run, which makes it difficult to offer help.

Here's a minimal version of your `UniversalTypesViewController` class (it uses your linked `SoundView` class):

```
final class UniversalTypesViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: Properties
    
    private lazy var soundView = SoundView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 80))
    private let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
    private var initialOffset: CGPoint = .zero
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        panGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(soundViewPanned(recognizer:)))
        soundView.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
    }
    
    private func animatedShowSoundView() {
        // reset soundView's transform
        soundView.transform = .identity
        // add it to the view
        view.addSubview(soundView)
        // position soundView near bottom, but past the right side of view
        soundView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width, y: view.frame.height - soundView.frame.height * 2.0)
        soundView.startSoundBarsAnimation()

        // animate soundView into view
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseOut) {
            self.soundView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -self.soundView.frame.width * 2.0, y: 0.0)
        }
    }
    
    private func animatedHideSoundView(toRight: Bool) {
        let translationX = toRight ? view.frame.width : -(view.frame.width + soundView.frame.width)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.soundView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: translationX, y: 0.0)
        } completion: { isFinished in
            if isFinished {
                self.soundView.removeFromSuperview()
                //self.songPlayer.pause()
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // if soundView is not in the view hierarchy,
        //  animate it into view - animatedShowSoundView() func adds it as a subview
        if soundView.superview == nil {
            animatedShowSoundView()
        } else {
            // unwrap the touch
            guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
            // get touch location
            let loc = touch.location(in: self.view)
            // if touch is inside the soundView frame,
            //  return, so pan gesture can move soundView
            if soundView.frame.contains(loc) { return }
            // if touch is on the left-half of the screen,
            //  animate soundView to the left and remove after animation
            if loc.x < view.frame.midX {
                animatedHideSoundView(toRight: false)
            } else {
                // touch is on the right-half of the screen,
                //  so just remove soundView
                animatedHideSoundView(toRight: true)
            }
        }
    }
    // MARK: Objc methods
    
    @objc private func soundViewPanned(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let touchPoint = recognizer.location(in: view)
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .began:
            initialOffset = CGPoint(x: touchPoint.x - soundView.center.x, y: touchPoint.y - soundView.center.y)
        case .changed:
            soundView.center = CGPoint(x: touchPoint.x - initialOffset.x, y: touchPoint.y - initialOffset.y)
        case .ended, .cancelled:
            ()
        default: break
        }
    }
    
}
```

If you run that, tapping anywhere will animate `soundView` into view at bottom-right. You can then drag `soundView` around.

If you tap away from `soundView` frame, on the ***left-half*** of the screen, `soundView` will be animated out to the ***left*** and removed after animation completes.

If you tap away from `soundView` frame, on the ***right-half*** of the screen, `soundView` will be animated out to the ***right*** and removed after animation completes.

Once you've got that working, and you see what's happening, you can implement it in the rest of your much-more-complex code.

---

**Edit**

Take a look at this modified version of your code.

One big problem in your code is that you're making multiple calls to `animatedHideSoundView()`. When the drag gets near the edge, your code calls that... but then it gets called again because the drag is still "active."

So, I added a `var isHideAnimationRunning: Bool` flag so calls to positioning when dragging and positioning when "hide" animating don't conflict.

A few other changes:

- instead of mixing Transforms with `.center` positioning, get rid of the Transforms and just use `.center`
- I created a struct with logically named corner points - makes it much easier to reference them
- strongly recommended: ***add comments to your code!***

So, give this a try:

```
import UIKit

let screenWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let screenHeight: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

let sideSpacing: CGFloat = 32.0
let mediumSpacing: CGFloat = 16.0

var isNewIphone: Bool {
    return screenHeight / screenWidth > 1.8
}

extension CGPoint {
    func distance(to point: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        return sqrt(pow(point.x - x, 2) + pow(point.y - y, 2))
    }
}

// so we can refer to corner positions by logical names
struct CornerPoints {
    var topLeft: CGPoint = .zero
    var bottomLeft: CGPoint = .zero
    var bottomRight: CGPoint = .zero
    var topRight: CGPoint = .zero
}

final class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var cornerPoints = CornerPoints()
    
    private let soundViewSide: CGFloat = 80.0
    private lazy var halfSoundViewWidth = soundViewSide / 2
    
    private lazy var newIphoneSpacing = isNewIphone ? mediumSpacing : 0.0
    
    private lazy var soundView = SoundView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: soundViewSide, height: soundViewSide)))
    
    private lazy var notHiddenSoundViewRect = CGRect(x: mediumSpacing, y: 0.0, width: screenWidth - mediumSpacing * 2, height: screenHeight)
    
    private var initialOffset: CGPoint = .zero
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow

        // setup corner points
        let left = sideSpacing + halfSoundViewWidth
        let right = view.frame.maxX - (sideSpacing + halfSoundViewWidth)
        let top = sideSpacing + halfSoundViewWidth - newIphoneSpacing
        let bottom = view.frame.maxY - (sideSpacing + halfSoundViewWidth - newIphoneSpacing)
        
        cornerPoints.topLeft        = CGPoint(x: left, y: top)
        cornerPoints.bottomLeft     = CGPoint(x: left, y: bottom)
        cornerPoints.bottomRight    = CGPoint(x: right, y: bottom)
        cornerPoints.topRight       = CGPoint(x: right, y: top)

        let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
        panGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(soundViewPanned(recognizer:)))
        soundView.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
        
        // for development, let's add a double-tap recognizer to
        //  add the soundView again (if it's been removed)
        let dt = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showAgain(_:)))
        dt.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        view.addGestureRecognizer(dt)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            self.animatedShowSoundView()
        }
    }
    
    @objc func showAgain(_ f: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // if soundView has been removed
        if soundView.superview == nil {
            // add it
            animatedShowSoundView()
        }
    }
    
    private func animatedShowSoundView() {
        // start at bottom-right, off-screen to the right
        let pt: CGPoint = cornerPoints.bottomRight
        soundView.center = CGPoint(x: screenWidth + soundViewSide, y: pt.y)
        
        view.addSubview(soundView)
        soundView.startSoundBarsAnimation()
        
        // animate to bottom-right corner
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseOut) {
            self.soundView.center = pt
        }
    }
    
    // flag so we know if soundView is currently
    //  "hide" animating
    var isHideAnimationRunning: Bool = false
    
    private func animatedHideSoundView(toRight: Bool) {
        
        // only execute if soundView is not currently "hide" animating
        if !isHideAnimationRunning {
            // set flag to true
            isHideAnimationRunning = true
            
            // target center X
            let targetX: CGFloat = toRight ? screenWidth + soundViewSide : -soundViewSide
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.soundView.center.x = targetX
            } completion: { isFinished in
                self.isHideAnimationRunning = false
                if isFinished {
                    self.soundView.removeFromSuperview()
                    //self.songPlayer.pause()
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    @objc private func soundViewPanned(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let touchPoint = recognizer.location(in: view)
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .began:
            // only execute if soundView is not currently "hide" animating
            if !isHideAnimationRunning {
                initialOffset = CGPoint(x: touchPoint.x - soundView.center.x, y: touchPoint.y - soundView.center.y)
            }
        case .changed:
            // only execute if soundView is not currently "hide" animating
            if !isHideAnimationRunning {
                soundView.center = CGPoint(x: touchPoint.x - initialOffset.x, y: touchPoint.y - initialOffset.y)
                if notHiddenSoundViewRect.minX > soundView.frame.minX {
                    animatedHideSoundView(toRight: false)
                } else if notHiddenSoundViewRect.maxX < soundView.frame.maxX {
                    animatedHideSoundView(toRight: true)
                }
            }
        case .ended, .cancelled:
            // only execute if soundView is not currently "hide" animating
            if !isHideAnimationRunning {
                let decelerationRate = UIScrollView.DecelerationRate.normal.rawValue
                let velocity = recognizer.velocity(in: view)
                let projectedPosition = CGPoint(
                    x: soundView.center.x + project(initialVelocity: velocity.x, decelerationRate: decelerationRate),
                    y: soundView.center.y + project(initialVelocity: velocity.y, decelerationRate: decelerationRate)
                )
                let nearestCornerPosition = nearestCorner(to: projectedPosition)
                let relativeInitialVelocity = CGVector(
                    dx: relativeVelocity(forVelocity: velocity.x, from: soundView.center.x, to: nearestCornerPosition.x),
                    dy: relativeVelocity(forVelocity: velocity.y, from: soundView.center.y, to: nearestCornerPosition.y)
                )
                let timingParameters = UISpringTimingParameters(dampingRatio: 0.8, initialVelocity: relativeInitialVelocity)
                let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.5, timingParameters: timingParameters)
                animator.addAnimations {
                    self.soundView.center = nearestCornerPosition
                }
                animator.startAnimation()
            }
        default: break
        }
    }
    
    private func project(initialVelocity: CGFloat, decelerationRate: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return (initialVelocity / 1000) * decelerationRate / (1 - decelerationRate)
    }
    
    private func nearestCorner(to point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        var minDistance = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
        var nearestPosition = CGPoint.zero
        
        for position in [cornerPoints.topLeft, cornerPoints.bottomLeft, cornerPoints.bottomRight, cornerPoints.topRight] {
            let distance = point.distance(to: position)
            if distance < minDistance {
                nearestPosition = position
                minDistance = distance
            }
        }
        return nearestPosition
    }
    
    /// Calculates the relative velocity needed for the initial velocity of the animation.
    private func relativeVelocity(forVelocity velocity: CGFloat, from currentValue: CGFloat, to targetValue: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        guard currentValue - targetValue != 0 else { return 0 }
        return velocity / (targetValue - currentValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Actually, I want the user to be able to swipe this soundView off the screen, rather than hide it on tap. 

That's why I check where the soundView is while the user is moving it, so that if he moves the soundView near the edge of the screen, I can hide the soundView animatedly. 

Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but I couldn't think of anything else, because I don't have much experience. Could you give me some advice on this? 

By the way, I tried calling animatedHideSoundView() not in switch recognizer.state, and then the completion block works correctly.

Comment: @IhorMyronishyn - I grabbed your GitHub project... see the **Edit** to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works correctly. I'm learning Swift on my own and I'm missing some helpful advice from more experienced developers. Thanks again, I will listen to your remarks.

Comment: Dear DonMag, I do not feel comfortable asking you for advice again, but my app is almost ready, all that remains is to fix this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73130038/problem-with-parallax-effect-animation-for-imageviews-in-swift
Could you help me with this problem? I would be very grateful.